# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.TransportChannelProvider

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using AWS Lambda in java and I'm trying to pull from the gcp pubsub queue.

```
private static SubscriberStub getSubscriber() throws IOException {
    SubscriberStubSettings subscriberStubSettings =
            SubscriberStubSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(new GcpCredentialsUtil().getCredentialsProvider())
                    .setTransportChannelProvider(
                            SubscriberStubSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder()
                                    .setMaxInboundMessageSize(20 * 1024 * 1024) // 20MB (maximum message size).
                                    .setKeepAliveWithoutCalls(false)
                                    .build())
                    .build();
    return GrpcSubscriberStub.create(subscriberStubSettings);
}
```

I'm using maven and I've added the dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>26.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try to run Lambda locally I have the error:

```
com/google/api/gax/rpc/TransportChannelProvider: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/rpc/TransportChannelProvider
        at lambdas.teams.ProcessMessageLambda.handleRequest(ProcessMessageLambda.java:33)
        at lambdas.teams.ProcessMessageLambda.handleRequest(ProcessMessageLambda.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.TransportChannelProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 2 more
```

TransportChannelProvider is present in mine ~/m2/repository, but I guess it's not present in runtime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding maven shade plugin resolved an issue:

```
<build>
    <finalName>lambdas</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```